# Issue Gitlab authentification LDAP

Tags: linux, authentication, gitlab, active-directory, ldap

I did all the instructions from the GitLab Documentation (Integrate LDAP with GitLab) but when I try to log with a ldap account I keep getting this error "Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials for X".

Here is the configuration of my file `gitlab.rb`:

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false

###! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: 'XX.XX.XX'
     port: 389
     uid: 'uid'
     bind_dn: 'CN=Administrateur,CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX'
     password: 'XX'
     encryption: 'plain'
     verify_certificates: true
     active_directory: true
     base: 'CN=GitLab,OU=XX,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX'
EOS
```

and when I do `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` I don't get any error.
Can somebody help me ?